# Most efficient way to find if row "a" has relation with row "b" in an ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4

This is my problem:

- I have a 1-N relationship between SomeTable and SomeOtherTable.
- User wants to modify row b, but he can only modify it if row a has a relationship with row b
- Therfore, I need to find if row a from SomeTable has a relationship with row b from SomeOtherTable

If you can, provide a general answer and then a specific answer for symfony 1.4 and doctrine. That would be useful for more people and for myself who works in multiple frameworks.

I need this to handle permissions on the CRUD of some tables.

I find that this is a very recurrent problem

Maybe there is a pattern or a plugin that solves this problem?

- How do you take the most advantage of symfony caching system?

Currently i just came up with this:

```
$someRow = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('SomeTable')->
  where('id = ?', $id_someTable)->
  andWhere('id_relation = ?',$id_someOtherTable)->execute();
return $someRow->count() > 0;
```

For some reason i find this ugly...

Comment: I feel like i didn't explain my problem properly... Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Your title is more explicit than your text, anyway.

You have a function [called `getRelations` in Table.php](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Table.php#L1009). So you can retrieve all relations to an object and then, make what ever you want with the result.

```
/**
 * Retrieves all relation objects defined on this table.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getRelations()
{
    return $this->_parser->getRelations();
}
```

So :

```
$relations = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SomeTable')->getRelations();
```

For more detail, [here is the parser getRelations method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php#L241).

**Edit:**

And if you want to try for a given relation, you can then use [`hasRelation`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php#L106).

Comment: I think my title is misleading. It should have said "most efficient way to find if object A has relation with object B in ORM"

Comment: I want to find if row from table A with id "a" has a relation with row from table B with id "b". I think you answer if table A has a relation with Table B